# Use of `create_app` parameter inside FlaskGroup

Tags: python, flask, flask-cli

I have flask application which uses application factory pattern to instantiate flask application. I am trying to integrate Flask CLI command line to my flask app.

Can any one help me in understanding the use of `create_app` parameter inside `FlaskGroup` call.

Following is my code snippet.

```
from project import create_app, db
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
app = create_app()
cli = FlaskGroup(create_app=create_app)
```

If i had used like normal flask application, then i would n't have to use `create_app` parameter, in which case my code snippet looks like

```
from project import app, db
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
cli = FlaskGroup(app)
```

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade to Flask 1.0. The `flask` command now understands how to work with factory functions.

```
FLASK_APP=myapp
flask run
```

Flask will import `myapp`, find the `create_app` function, and call it to get an app object. See [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/cli/) for more info.

---

Assuming you actually want a custom `cli` object (you most likely don't), then you're using it correctly. You pass the factory function to the group and it will call it when it needs the app object.